# set first value on vaadin-combo-box

Tags: javascript, polymer, vaadin

I've HTML forms with vaadin-combo-box inside, the value of the item is from a reference query. I succeed to set selected value to save into main data but unfortunately, I still have no idea how to set first value onload

I just try this but found no error either no display

html :

```
<form id="form">    
  <div>[[data.id]]<input size="1" name="id" value$='[[data.id]]'></div> 
  <div>
    <iron-ajax url="url" last-response="{{response}}" auto></iron-ajax>
    <vaadin-combo-box selected-item="{{No}}" placeholder="Please select" items=[[response]]" ></vaadin-combo-box>
  </div>                                                                
</form>
```

js :

```
ready(){
  document.querySelectorAll('vaadin-combo-box').forEach(function(comboBox) {
  document.querySelectorAll('vaadin-combo-box').value = 
    $(this.$.form).serializeJSON().regNo ;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('vaadin-combo-box').forEach(function(comboBox) {
    //write all the options in combo box as an array and assign it to comboBox.items
    comboBox.items = ["a","b","C"]; //This is an example array. 
    comboBox.value = $(this.$.form).serializeJSON().regNo;
});
```

But if you have only one "vaadin-combo-box" in your entier page, then

```
comboBox = document.querySelector('vaadin-combo-box')       
//set all the options in combo box as an array and assign it to comboBox.items
comboBox.items = ["a","b","C"]; //This is an example array. 
comboBox.value = $(this.$.form).serializeJSON().regNo;
```

For further details, check https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/html-examples

Comment: still not works @murali but i just found the solution as below : <vaadin-combo-box selected-item="{{No}}" placeholder="Please select" items=[[response]]"   value$='[[data.No]]'></vaadin-combo-box> .. thx for your response anyway

Comment: Good to hear you found solution. May I know what's the problem.

Comment: only add value$='[[data.No]]'